# What is the difference between `von an` und ´ab´?

Tags: difference

Wie lange lernst du schon Deutsch?
Should I use "von April an" or "ab April"?
This question makes me mad:(

Comment: Ich... langst. Und ich lebe in Deutschland. Muttersprächler würden beide verstehen, aber nur eine von diesen ist okay, und ich kann nicht sagen, welche. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Neither.

It is "seit April".

"Ab April" and "von April an" can only be used for actions starting in the future.